# Windows 8.1 Laptop; Is there a way for closed lid to cause sleep but not when there is a monitor hooked up?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, sleep, power-management, external-display

Is it possible to make a laptop sleep when the lid is closed UNLESS there is an external monitor that is plugged in? Perhaps a registry hack or third party software?

The control panel power settings seem to allow for closing the computer's lid to have different effects when the computer is on battery power vs. plugged in, but there is no option to have the computer sleep when the lid is closed UNLESS it is attached to an external monitor.

When I am at my desk, I use my HDMI monitor and I like to have my laptop shut and tucked away in a corner. Whenever I am not at my desk and I instinctively shut my computer, it's still running.

I imagine this is a reasonably common problem and there is an easy solution, but I've been unable to find it so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I personally don't think it's a "reasonably common problem" being an individual that uses laptop+extra monitor (and having 3+ years of computer repair and coding experience). The main issue being the fact that you prefer/expect the computer to be "tucked" away while still utilizing. The only chance you stand is some crazy custom `powercfg` settings. >> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx << that is, if it's even available. If not, in tandem with some scheduled task? ie:`taskschd.msc`

Comment: Why not set the power button as sleep? Hit the button, close lid.

Comment: @Papa, the OP wants what you suggest, **except** `if` connected to external monitor.

Comment: @BiTinerary: I *do* think it's a reasonably common problem, and is particularly common in corporations that use laptops with docking stations.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq: And you would be wrong. Most corporations use one or the other of the "Big ones". I admit being skewed as a former DELL DCSE, but it's still valid point: you order from supplier who offers you best deal on support. Which includes rollout packages and lots of business functionality and support for docking. For lack of better examples: most big firms were using Precision/Optiplex workstations for desktops, latitude for laptops. Which are good business designs and well equipped as such, but not really good for home use. And business users sign "terms of use" or similar...

Comment: Making them responsible for equipment. Of course, most also buys complete coverage so I've seen laptops abused like nowhere else, but it's a pain to use replacement machine when yours is in repair... So either computers already are well suited and/or setup for internal use rules or no one cares if user needs to push a button once a day...

Comment: @AcePL: Once again, you're talking rubbish. Plenty of corporations support their own IT and couldn't care less about Dell or other OEM "support" beyond hardware coverage. Some are constrained by national agreements and get no choice on who they buy from. And the current national HP business notebooks the previous Dell AND the prior Toshiba systems have absolutely ZERO software the does what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do in your place:

1. Use scripts or shortcuts to switch between active power profiles
2. Create custom power profile which doesn't sleep when lid closed
3. Use script to detect HDMI state and run switching scripts accordingly.

All is certainly doable. Not easy, but doable.

Personal advice, though - I wouldn't. sleeping with lid closed is not perfect and too many times I pulled out a laptop from a bag fully powered on. And HOT.
I set up options so hitting power button sends it to sleep, wait it's off and only then I'm packing. I don't want to fry my machine...

Comment: Absolutely legit concern. It could very easily go from **minor** convenience too utter disaster. Additionally as you mention, it wouldn't be easy. OP would have to learn specific `powercfg` flags to designate the power profiles on top of putting together (what I would estimate to be in python) a 75-100 lines of code. So, @qasdfdsaq be my guest if it's in such high demand. Also consider the fact that the "corps" you mention, simply aren't utilizing better alternatives or good technical procedure.

Comment: My solution has so many possible fail points and/or admin privileges requirements that i doubt any company would agree to such mod. So a moot point, IMO.

Comment: @AcePL I appreciate the idea with the scripts. The bag situation is exactly what happened to me, and I realized that I needed a more responsible solution.

Comment: @CalebC: Unfortunately I can't see one. And there are so many fail points in my solution that I really discourage it. For example: for last two days power saving options were working worse than a lame duck. No screen dimming, no sleep option in power options, windows working weird... All because of some error within Windows Update. Had to reboot and only then all was fine once again. Rest assured script would fail ATP. So again: do you really want to chance it?

Answer (score 0):

How to Turn Off Laptop Screen When Using HDMI Windows 8.1:
The windows-key (bottom left next to alt key) + p
I have an HP pavilion (I think) and a screen pops out with all the options.
Not sure what happens at reboot. I'm assuming you would need to repeat after reboot  (But I'm not trying to find my way back here after test :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).